How to right split n times in python polars dataframe (mimic pandas rsplit)
I have a column of strings where the end portion has some information I need to parse into its own columns. Pandas has the rsplit function to split a string from the right, which does exactly what I need:
import polars as pl
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "name": [
            "some_name_set_1",
            "some_name_set_1b",
            "some_other_name_set_2",
            "yet_another_name_set_2",
        ]
    }
)

df.to_pandas()["name"].str.rsplit("_", n=2, expand=True)

                  0    1   2
0         some_name  set   1
1         some_name  set  1b
2   some_other_name  set   2
3  yet_another_name  set   2

How can I mimic this behavior in Polars, which doesn't have an rsplit expression right now?

A single char separator can also be expressed in terms of regex:
df.select(
   pl.col("name").str.extract_groups(r"(.+)_([^_]+)_([^_]+)$")
     .struct.unnest()
)

shape: (4, 3)
┌──────────────────┬─────┬─────┐
│ 1                ┆ 2   ┆ 3   │
│ ---              ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ str              ┆ str ┆ str │
╞══════════════════╪═════╪═════╡
│ some_name        ┆ set ┆ 1   │
│ some_name        ┆ set ┆ 1b  │
│ some_other_name  ┆ set ┆ 2   │
│ yet_another_name ┆ set ┆ 2   │
└──────────────────┴─────┴─────┘

But it is not a general solution (limited to single chars) and the regexes can be awkward to re-read.

Nice! That's a lot less typing than my solution.

Here's one way using only one .split and then three different slice/get operations to get the 3 parts:
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "name": [
            "some_name_set_1",
            "some_name_set_1b",
            "some_other_name_set_2",
            "yet_another_name_set_2",
        ]
    }
)

df = df.select(parts=pl.col("name").str.split("_")).select(
    a=pl.col("parts").list.slice(0, pl.col("parts").list.len() - 2).list.join("_"),
    b=pl.col("parts").list.get(-2),
    c=pl.col("parts").list.get(-1),
)

print(df)

Output:
shape: (4, 3)
┌──────────────────┬─────┬─────┐
│ a                ┆ b   ┆ c   │
│ ---              ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ str              ┆ str ┆ str │
╞══════════════════╪═════╪═════╡
│ some_name        ┆ set ┆ 1   │
│ some_name        ┆ set ┆ 1b  │
│ some_other_name  ┆ set ┆ 2   │
│ yet_another_name ┆ set ┆ 2   │
└──────────────────┴─────┴─────┘

Related: This issue is tracking addition of right splitting of strings.

Thanks! Much more readable than my solution. Glad to see an issue tracking right split.

One solution is to do this in two parts
For the name portion (the left side of the string):

Split the list
Reverse the list
Get the 3rd through n-th items of the list
Reverse the list again
Join the list with original delimiter

For the set and number portion:

Split the list
Get the second-to-last item through the end
Convert to struct and unnest

pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "name": [
            "some_name_set_1",
            "some_name_set_1b",
            "some_other_name_set_2",
            "yet_another_name_set_2",
        ]
    }
).with_columns(
    pl.col("name")
    .str.split("_")
    .list.reverse()
    .list.slice(2)
    .list.reverse()
    .list.join("_"),
    pl.col("name")
    .str.split("_")
    .list.slice(-2, None)
    .list.to_struct()
    .alias("end_stuff"),
).unnest("end_stuff")


shape: (4, 3)
┌──────────────────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│ name             ┆ field_0 ┆ field_1 │
│ ---              ┆ ---     ┆ ---     │
│ str              ┆ str     ┆ str     │
╞══════════════════╪═════════╪═════════╡
│ some_name        ┆ set     ┆ 1       │
│ some_name        ┆ set     ┆ 1b      │
│ some_other_name  ┆ set     ┆ 2       │
│ yet_another_name ┆ set     ┆ 2       │
└──────────────────┴─────────┴─────────┘

